# Unable to resize view in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I can't seem to resize my view to fill the screen in the simulator (see screenshot below - notice the top and bottom black lines) does anyone know how i fix this?

[image]

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: If you dont add launch screen xib then it will thinks your app is made for older device thus the screen will have low resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of this issue is you have not added launch images or storyboard in your project.

You either need to add launch images to your `xcasset` folder or you need to create `storyboard` for launch.

This is not the issue with auto layout.

Answer (score 1):

One common reason for this sort of letterboxing is that your app project lacks launch images for all device sizes. An easy way to get past that hurdle is to use a *LaunchScreen.storyboard*. Make a completely new project in a modern version of Xcode, and you will see that it has a *LaunchScreen.storyboard* for this very reason.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the AutoLayout and set the Top and Bottom of your view to have zero distance w.r.t the Top Layout and Bottom Layout.
Similarly also set the X coordinate of your view using the Autolayout.

Thanks